# Can you provide authentication in the Play framework?

Tags: authentication, playframework

I have been reading about the Play Framework.  It is said to be pretty nice, easy to work with and "fun."  I also have read that it makes stateless applications.  However, I can't think of many things to build that I would want to be truly stateless.

I would hope that I can at least have a user log in and create security and user privileges around that authentication.  Is that possible to do in the Play Framework?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the difference between a stageful and a stateless framework. It does not say that you cannot save state, it just means you save state in a persistent store, like a Database, or temporarily in a Cache. Over-use of sessions as more than conversational state, is argued to be an anti pattern.

Comment: I did misunderstand.  I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide8

Comment: That will certainly work.  Is Play really as good as they say?